# Icinga2 object ApiUser is unknown

Tags: api, nagios, icinga

I need help understanding an error why I'm seeing an error. 
The feature `api` is already enabled with the correct ApiListener object, and Api logs are being updated in `/var/lib/icinga2/api/log/current` .

But I'm getting this error when I restart icinga2:

```
Error: Error while evaluating expression: The type 'ApiUser' is unknown: in /etc/icinga2/conf.d/api-users.conf: 1:0-1:20
```

I'm running version r2.3.10-1 of Icinga2 on Ubuntu.

Can someone explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably mixing the current snapshot packages with the released stable versions. The 'ApiUser' object is part of the upcoming Icinga 2 v2.4 release and only available in git master (and therefore snapshot packages as well as docs). The stable 2.3.x tree does not have that kind of configuration object type and therefore bails out with an error.

Remove that file or its content, you don't need it for 2.3.x.

Comment: thanks, but they do not notify us about versioning problems :( http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/snapshot/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/icinga2-api  
https://dev.icinga.org/versions/241 
hm, does it mean that with 2.3 I am unable use API?

Comment: You're reading the *snapshot* documentation, which is using the git master and therefore unreleased content. the api is planned for icinga2 v2.4 which is scheduled for November being released. Please use the latest documentation for 2.3.x as linked on docs.icinga.org

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand even if I have current log in _/var/lib/icinga2/api/log/current_, I can't use api until v2.4 release?

Comment: the api log is different (that's the cluster replay log). you don't need an ApiUser object for that - the latter is used for a 2.4+ feature only.

Comment: @dnsmichi freenode which is specified on the icinga website doesn't working. Can you give us a true way to talk with you?

Comment: I'm fairly active at monitoring-portal.org, the mailing lists, and sometimes IRC. Though you might just wanna ask the community over there as well. The IRC web chat on free node works fine for me (http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=icinga) but if not, use your own client (irssi, adium, quassel, etc.)